# How to create Side by side scrollable carousel

Tags: css, reactjs

I'm creating website using react.js - bootstrap and I wanted to create a carousel like the picture Below. So the middle part will be kind a little pop up (like there's a little shadow and we can swipe to left or right to see the other card in the middle)

[image]

How can I achieve this design ? Is there any package that already exist for this kind of design ?

Answer (score 0):

I would look into Swiper.js, don't think they have your desired result straight out of the box, but would be a good starting point. You can then try to conditionally add a class to the "active" card to give it the pop effect.

Docs: https://swiperjs.com/demos